# Apple Mach-O Linker Error with upnpx library

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, upnp, upnpx

I am having a small problem when using the upnpx library.

I have downloaded the library and opened the upnpdemo workspace. I created in the same workspace a new project to try to create a simple app with this library. I set the parameters like a demo project, but XCode returns 21 errors:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"std::string::find(char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new project's build settings, set the **C++ Language Dialect** and **C++ Standard Library** to `Compiler Default` for both of them.

Comment: thanks, they are set to 'Compiler Default' but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you build upnpx.a with

```
**C++ Language Dialect** GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]
**C++ Standard Library** libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)
```

In your project you must
iOS Deployment Target 7.0 or above

If you get upnpx.a from web, you can try to lower the Deployment target, 6.

And DO NOT FORGET

```
**Other Linker Flags**: -lstdc++
```